# render usercontrol (cshtml) using @Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls

I am getting my hands on MVC 3 and am confused that how do i use UserControls in my project.

I have created a usercontrol (cshtml) file called UserControl.cshtml and i am trying to render it Products.cshtml.

MyUserControl.cshtml resides in Shared folder.

In Products.cshtml:

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("MyUserControl.cshtml");
</div>
```

But i am getting this error. I dont know why is it trying to search .ascx file.:

```
The partial view 'MyUserControl.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Products/MyUserControl.cshtml.aspx
~/Views/Products/MyUserControl.cshtml.ascx
~/Views/Shared/MyUserControl.cshtml.aspx
~/Views/Shared/MyUserControl.cshtml.ascx
```

Is this the correct way to render usercontrol in mvc 3?

--Update--

This works.

```
@RenderPage("../Shared/MyUserControl.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to specify the file extension, the view engine will handle that.

```
@Html.Partial("MyUserControl")
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. What if i want some action of MyUserControl to be invoked bydefault when it loads? Just like Page_Load method of Asp.Net Usercontrol. How do i do that? I dont want to call @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "MyUserControl");} in Products.cshtml.

Answer (score 2):

Phil haack has fantastic blog on the way to use Partial page.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx